# Question regarding proof of validity of a modulus expression

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We must prove $n^{13} - 5n^8 + n \equiv (2n^7 + 9n^2) \pmod{14}$ for any natural number $n$.

I have no idea what to do. I tried assuming that $n^{12} - 5n^7 + 1 - 2n^6 - 9n + r = 14k$ where $r$ and $k$ are natural numbers. But that did not lead anywhere.

Comment: When $n=2$, the expression evaluates to 3311 and is not a multiple of 2 (and hence not a multiple of 14 either).

Comment: @Muralidharan : sorry, I mistyped the original question!

Comment: i got $n=1$ or $n=8$

Comment: It's equivalent to proving that $n^{13}-5n^8-2n^7-9n^2+n\equiv0\pmod{14}$ for every natural number n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n^{13}-5n^8 +n - 2n^7-9n^2$ is always even and hence it is enough to prove this is a multiple of 7. Since $n^7 = n \mod 7$ for all $n$, we have
$$n^{13}-5n^8 +n - 2n^7-9n^2 = n - 5n^2 +n - 2n - 9n^2 \mod 7 = 14 n^2 \mod 7 = 0 $$